# Redirect to cms page if searched product is not found

Tags: magento-2.1, cms, search

I need to redirect the customer to a cms page if the product customer searches are not found and if the product is found then Magento redirects it to result in a page which is the default functionality.

How can I prevent redirect to result in the page if no product matches search query?

Can someone please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps:

**Step-1:** go to "app" from root directory of Magento 2 and create new directory code. Then create two more directories in app/code, Namespace and Module Name. The final directory will look like this: **app/code/Demo/SearchRedirect**

**Demo** as Namespace and **SearchRedirect** as module name.

**Step-2:** create **registration.php** file in **app/code/Demo/SearchRedirect/** and paste below code into the file:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Demo_SearchRedirect',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step-3:** create **module.xml** file in **app/code/Demo/SearchRedirect/etc** and paste below code into the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Demo_SearchRedirect" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="CatalogSearch"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step-4:** create **di.xml** file in **app/code/Demo/SearchRedirect/etc** and paste below code into the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result">
        <plugin name="catalog-search-result-redirect" type="Demo\SearchRedirect\Plugin\Result" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Step-5:** create **Result.php** file in **app/code/Demo/SearchRedirect/Plugin** and paste below code into the file:

```
<?php
namespace Demo\SearchRedirect\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http as HttpResponse;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface as UrlInterface;

class Result
{
    /**
     * @var HttpResponse
     */
    protected $response;

    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlInterface;

    public function __construct(
        HttpResponse $response,
        UrlInterface $urlInterface
    )
    {
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    }


    public function aroundGetResultCount(\Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        $result = $proceed();
        $resultCount = $subject->getData('result_count');
        if($resultCount <= 0)
        {
            $this->response->setRedirect($this->urlInterface->getUrl('customer-service'));
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Setp-6** Run below commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```